# How to plot highest highs and lowest lows properly?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm trying to plot highest highs and lowest lows with the code below, but it seems sometimes the lines reposition themselves without high and low prices.

```
   timeframe = 72

   highestHigh = highest(high, timeframe)
   lowestLow = lowest(low, timeframe)

   plot(highestHigh)
   plot(lowestLow)
```

In the screenshots below, note that the behavior seems correct where I've added arrows, but I have no idea why they are changing their positions where I've marked with circles.

It seems to happen with every symbol I try. In the screenshots, I'm using `XRPUSDT` as an example.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't help without code snippet that compiles and reproduces the unexpected behavior, along with accompanying chart with symbol/TF information.

Comment: Look what happens on the chart 72 bars ago, relative to the circles you specified.